# PieChart change format float to int MPAndroidChart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I tried to implement setValueFormatter method but that method is always red " cant resolve symboll" error

```js
mChart.setValueFormatter(new myFormAT())
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`ValueFormatter`](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/The-ValueFormatter-interface) can be set for [`DataSet`](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartLib/src/main/java/com/github/mikephil/charting/data/DataSet.java) and not for [Chart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartLib/src/main/java/com/github/mikephil/charting/charts/Chart.java) object.

Example:

```
ValueFormatter formatter = new ValueFormatter() {
    @Override
    public String getFormattedValue(float value, Entry entry, int dataSetIndex, ViewPortHandler viewPortHandler) {
        return ((int) value) + " " + currency;
    }
};
dataSet.setValueFormatter(formatter);
```

Comment: it woks when we set formatter on PieData not in PieDataSet.

Answer (score 1):

```
  PieDataSet dataSet = new PieDataSet(entries, "");
    dataSet.setValueFormatter(new IValueFormatter() {
        @Override
        public String getFormattedValue(float value, Entry entry, int dataSetIndex, ViewPortHandler viewPortHandler) {
            return String.valueOf((int) value);
        }
    })
```

Comment: `error: method getFormattedValue(float,Entry,int,ViewPortHandler) is already defined in class <anonymous com.thumbsol.accuratemobileassetsmanagament.fragment.SalesFragment$1>
            public String getFormattedValue(float value, Entry entry, int dataSetIndex, ViewPortHandler viewPortHandler) {`

getting this error